# Split list returned from urlparse in python

Tags: python, split, urllib, urlparse, urlsplit

I am able to parse url using `urlsplit` and get parameters using `query` argument.

`url` is `'/api/v1/test?par1=val1&par2=val2a%3D1%26val2b%3Dfoo%26val2c%3Dbar'`

After using urlsplit and query I get

`'par1=val1&par2=val2a%3D1%26val2b%3Dfoo%26val2c%3Dbar'`

And after running parse_qs on above I get

`{'par2': ['val2a=1&val2b=foo&val2c=bar'], 'par1': ['val1']}`

Here is output which is exactly what I need

`'par1': ['val1']`

I get return as list for one of parameter which has decoded data as below

`'par2': ['val2a=1&val2b=foo&val2c=bar]`

I can split `par2` using `split` method at `&` and `=` and get `val2a`...

But is there any better way for this?

Comment: Please add the `url` which you are parsing as well.

Comment: @AKS updated with url

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can again use `parse_qs` on the value of `par2`

```
>>> url = '/api/v1/test?par1=val1&par2=val2a%3D1%26val2b%3Dfoo%26val2c%3Dbar'
>>> q = parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)
>>> q
{'par2': ['val2a=1&val2b=foo&val2c=bar'], 'par1': ['val1']}
>>> parse_qs(q['par2'][0])
{'val2b': ['foo'], 'val2c': ['bar'], 'val2a': ['1']}
```

After the last result you can get the value of `val2a` etc.

Answer (score 1):

`split` on `&` and `partition` on `=` is probably the easiest and most efficient way.

```
result = {k: v for k, _, v in (pair.partition('=') for pair in values.split('&'))}
# or
result = dict(pair.split('=') for pair in values.split('&'))
```

Using `re.sub()` is another option but I believe it's just over complicating stuff.